# Jack and Jill throw die, where the first person to throw a double wins. Jack throws first. What is the probability of Jill winning on her second turn.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Jack and Jill are taking turns throwing a pair of dice. The first person to throw a double wins the game. Jack rolls first. Find the probability that Jill wins the game on her second turn.

I believe that the answer is $\frac{125}{1296}$, and I got this by multiplying each expected event by each other ($\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac16$). Could anybody please confirm this, or otherwise tell me how to do the question if I am wrong.

Comment: I confirm your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is infact correct, the probability of Jill winning on her second turn = p(Jack doesn't throw a double)*p(Jill doesn't throw a double)*p(Jack doesn't throw a double)*p(Jill throws a double)= $\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac16=\frac{125}{1296}$

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is very hard to read. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your mathematical expressions.